# How do I use IBM Watson's Visual Recognition service with Dart in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I want to use IBM Watson's recognition service, specifically their waste identifier as shown below. https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/artificial-intelligence/patterns/recycle-with-watson/

It only talks about using it in an iOS application but I want to use it with Dart in Flutter. I am not too clear how to do this so if someone can teach me some of the basics of this that would be great. Btw, I do not want to train a IBM visual recog. model, I want to use the classifier that IBM provides as shown in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to start with the [Getting Started](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-getting-started-tutorial#getting-started-tutorial) which shows how to provision the Visual Recognition service. The next step is to either [reuse their server application](https://github.com/IBM/watson-waste-sorter/blob/master/server/run.py) which includes loading the training data or to explore writing your own. See the docs for links to either the API (works with every programming language) or SDKs for some more common programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

There is easy-to-follow [API doc](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v3) to help you to get started with Visual Recognition service.

Flutter has a very good documentation on how to make API calls in their [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

***Not recommended** but to help you with the basics* - There is an old [Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ibm_watson#-example-tab-) (last updated in 2018) that has Dart code samples to get you started.